# слитное или раздельное написание не(похоже)

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Подскажите, пожалуйста, слитно или раздельно: совсем на нее не()похоже

Answer (score 1):

Лет двадцать назад был бы однозначный ответ: только раздельно. Но в современном языке есть тенденция все чаще и чаще писать наречия с НЕ слитно. Например, в "Словаре трудностей русского языка" издания 2003 г. читаем: "*Не случайно* – только раздельно". Но фактически все чаще и чаще пишут слитно.

То же происходит и с другими наречиями, да и прилагательными тоже, и с причастиями.

Все же рекомендую раздельное написание.